ErrorElement не отображатеся при ошибках в запросах axios в react js
возник вопрос, использую react-router-dom и errorElement, когда делаю запрос на сервер перед рендером моей страницы
   try {
     const response = await getUserData(id);
     setUser(response.data);
     console.log(response.data);
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
     throw error;
   }
 }, [id]);```
и прокидываю ошибку у меня не отрисовывется errorElement 
 ```const router = createBrowserRouter([
   {
     element: (
       <FetchTriggerProvider>
         <DashboardLayout>
           <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
             <Outlet />
           </Suspense>
         </DashboardLayout>
       </FetchTriggerProvider>
     ),
     children: routes,
     errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
   },
   {
     path: LOGIN_URL,
     element: <LoginPage />,
   },
 ]);

 return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};```
в ErrorPage использую 
```const error = useRouteError();```
для запросов на сервер использую axios

